# which one is cleaner : put conditional statement on view or model?

Tags: php, coding-style, yii

I'm a Yii developer who want to follow MVC pattern.

In one part of my current project I have to check a special condition and according to it's result show a list of something to user. I want to determine if the user is *admin* or a *guest*.

There is two choice for me here, one is to determine two method one for *admin* and one for other user and check if the user is *admin* or not in the view, something like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => $tableName . "_grid",
    'dataProvider' => (Yii::app()->user->id == User::ADMIN) ? $model->search() : $model->getMyList(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
....
```

or change the `getMineList` method in the model. By this fact that I can't put this statement in the controller which one is better and cleaner?

Comment: Better to use condition `Yii::app()->user->id == User::ADMIN` into $model->search()

Answer (score 4):

The best way would to do the logic in the model by changing the getMineList or, as GBD stated, implement it into the search method of the model